# How to store a string input into different variables?

Tags: java, string, variables, input, storage

In my program I want to take an input from the user in the format of "String Int Int". 
For example, "F 5 200".

I then want to store these values into three different variables. 
How would I go about doing this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

 public static void main(String args[])
   {
      String s;

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter a command");
      s = in.nextLine();

      String str = s; 
        String[] arrOfStr = str.split(" ", 3); 

        for (String a : arrOfStr) 
            System.out.println(a); 



   }

}
```

I've got to the point of splitting the string and outputting the result. However I'm not sure how to store the outputs into variables with the correct data type.

Answer (score 1):

The three values are available in the array arrOfStr. So you could have three variables and assign each of them to arrOfStr[0], arrOfStr[1] and arrOfStr[2].

so the code snippet could look like the below in this case

```
String[] arrOfStr = str.split(" ", 3); 
String c = arrOfStr[0];
int val1 = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[1]);
int val2 = Integer.parseInt(arrOfStr[2]);
```

Comment: You can't assign a String to an int variable, as your code does with val1 and val2. So I had to downvote that. Please correct that, and I'll happily upvote.

Comment: Still using char instead of String for `c` (what I missed when reading first).

Answer (score 1):

They are all String variables so you realy have to know the order of the data so you can parse the string into int type

```
   String[] arrOfStr = str.split(" ", 3);
 String str1 =  arrOfStr[0];
 int int2 = Integer.parseInt (arrOfStr[1]);
 int int3 =  Integer.parseInt (arrOfStr [2]);
```

Comment: You can't assign a String to a char variable, as your code does with str1. So I had to downvote that. Please correct that, and I'll happily upvote.

Comment: Yes my bad i missed that